# GraphQL cursor-based pagination converted into page or offset pagination

Tags: search, pagination, graphql, algolia, graphql-ruby

Our app uses Algolia for searching which allows for two typical forms of pagination: by page `page=3&hitsPerPage=5` or by offset `offset=10&length=5`

GraphQL preferences cursor-based pagination where a recordID and length are provided `friendsConnection(first:5 after:"Y3Vyc29yMQ==")`

Is there anyway to translate info from a cursor-based pagination request into a page or offset pagination request?

Answer (score 1):

Depending what you use Algolia for (having all records available), you're able to use the `index.browseFrom` method. This will use a cursor. The documentation for that is [here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/browse/?language=javascript)

Comment: As browse methods browseParameters has limited features such as no support for facets we can't use browseFrom. Thanks anyways

Comment: Then you'll be stuck with offset or pagination, something interesting to keep in mind though, thanks for bringing it up!